# A script that counts and prints every ocurrence of not any file inside a common subfolder in a specific path

Tags: batch-file

Although I'm really a newbie in this field, I want to accomplish a task in batch scripting:  There is a determinate folder of company contracts in a determinate path, each of this folders (approx. 400) has a common folder (2016) where there might be a file indicating there has been an inspection in this year.  What i want is to print every company folder that has not any file in the common 2016 folder and a count of the times this happens.
This is what i have (and does not work at all):

```
set c=0
for %i /d in (*) do
for %j in ($%i\2016\*) do
if (%j==NUL) then (@echo $%i c+=1 echo %c)`
```

Comment: Ok, so have you tried **anything**?

Comment: This is what i have (and does not work at all):  `set c=0
for %i /d in (*) do 
for %j in ($%i\2016\*) do 
if (%j==NUL) then (@echo $%i c+=1 echo %c)`

Comment: @schwartz You should put this in your question (formatted as code)

Comment: Can you give us examples of the folder structure? Are the "company contracts" always one folder deep? Is the inspection file always the same name?

Comment: The folder structure would be: ‘somePath>companyA>2016>someFile. somePath>companyB>2016>someFile. somePath>companyC>2016>nothingHere. somePath>companyD>2016>someFile. somePath>companyE>2016>nothingHere. ...`The name of the inspection file doesn't matter. What matters is if there is one. Company contracts, yes, are all hanging on the same folder. I'm working on a solution, but I'm on the bus. Sorry for my "worse than worst" code. Things are beginning to click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if there is a file in the 2016 directory you can do this:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
for %%i /d in (*) do (
    REM first unset variable
    set files=
    for %%j in (%%i\2016\*) do (
        REM will set variable each time a file is encountered
        set files=present
    )
    if not DEFINED files (
        REM No files in directory 2016
        echo %%i
        set /a count+=1
        echo !count!
    )
)

EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

I don't see why you use `$` before each `%i`. If you execute this code from the command line use one `%` for the loop variables `i` and `j`. But in a batch-script you'll have to use two of them (`%%i`, `%%j`).

Another thing, `c+=1` won't work except if you use `set /a`.
I used [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) because each block code ( between `(...)`) is parsed as one single command (as if it was all on one line with `&&` between the commands inside the block) and you can't just assign a new value to a variable and read that new value in the same command. That's also the reason why I use `!count!` instead of `%count%` (which will give the value before the block). If you'd rather not use delayed expansion, remove the `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and replace `echo !count!` with `call echo %%count%%` (is another way to read a new value in the same command)

Also, be aware that each `echo` will end its output with a carriage retur and a newline. So each `echo` will result in a new line of output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! I made some modifications like writing to a csv and using dir for wildcards... But it took me a lot of time to find a working solution to the basic idea like yours!